# How can I make MongoMapper use short, auto-incremented integral IDs instead of those ridiculously long default ones?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm writing bug-tracking software in Ruby using Sinatra and MongoMapper. The problem is that the ticket IDs aren't very user friendly; they are composed of 24 hexadecimal digits (e.g. `4fcfa9e1c3e7f20bc2000004`). I would like that the ticket IDs start at 1 and automatically increment (i.e. 1, 2, 3…). In MySQL this would be done using `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

I'm using MongoMapper, however. Is there a way to make the IDs start at 1 and then auto-increment, or do I need to store them *separately*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have lots and lots of object creation, it may not scale b/c you have to hit the DB for every new object.

If you won't need that kind of scaling, there's a couple gems out there to allow incremental id's.

Pablo Cantero's gem, [mongomapper_id2](https://github.com/phstc/mongomapper_id2).

My gem, [mongo_sequence](https://github.com/brianhempel/mongo_sequence#why).

Be on the lookout, there may be a few places where MongoMapper has special behavior for `ObjectID`'s that doesn't work with integers. I at least know that as of a year and a half ago all the basic stuff works fine with integer id's.

Comment: `mongomapper_id2` stores them in a separate field (i.e. not in `_id`). This seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

The [MongoDB docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field) list some strategies for auto-incrementing IDs.

In general, the problem with auto-incremented IDs is that they don't scale. With auto-increment, you need a single entity to provide the keys and this becomes a bottleneck. So the default is to use Object IDs.

That stated, your rate of creation is probably not that fast and you may be able to leverage the ideas in the linked document. Also, you may want to look at something like JIRA where the ID is generated in some rational way with regards to the project.

Comment: +1. The OPs question implies that all clients share the counter, or each client must have its own collection/database. I agree the ticket id and the primary key shouldn't be the same value.